# Cursor height on safari browser is too tall however on chrome its fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

Theres an issue with the cursor on the “subscribeform” on the safari browser. The cursor is Too long when the input field is onFocus()!. But its fine on chrome. Please check image below. How to Fix? any advice appreciated thanks.

[image]

Code: HTML

```
<!--========== Notify Me ==========-->
            <form action="php/subscribe.php" id="subscribeform" class="row newsletter-form mb-lg" method="post">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control alt" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" onfocus="this.select()">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="submit" id="js-subscribe-btn"><img src="images/right-angle-white.png" alt=""></button>
            </span>
```

Code CSS

```
.form-control.alt {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I even tried this and nothing changed:

```
.form-control.alt {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  padding: 50px 30px 50px 80px;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with padding settings of the input instead, while leaving the `line-height` set to `normal`

Comment: Hey Neha thanks for the suggestion, check the updated answer, I tried to experiment with the padding, but the browser isn't effecting any changes. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong I wonder what it is.

However when I change the background color it changes, just not the padding. strange.... humm

Answer (score 0):

According to my experiences padding style can cause taller caret in safari. Try to remove padding style totally.

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at the `line-height` property or try adding more padding to your input

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, I already tried this. Check out the updated question. Any other ideas?